# JPA mapping for a List or Set<String>

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, orm

Being new to ORM, I'd like to find a way to define a simple (meaning without an additional entity) mapping for a list (or a set) of strings within an entity. I found this sample:

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "tags")
  private Set<String> tags;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Set<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
  }

  public void setTags(Set<String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }
}
```

which seems to fit my needs. However, processing this class with Eclipse's `hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl`, I end up with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl (default) on
>   project test-database: Execution default of goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl failed: Could
>   not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Book, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(tags)] -> [Help 1]

Specifying `@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)` did not help. Adding a column definition to the `tags` field (`@Column(name = "tags", columnDefinition="character varying (255)", nullable = false)`) leads to a successful build but produces this SQL:

```sql
create table Book (
    id int8 not null,
    tags character varying (255) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

which is not what I want, as I was expecting to end up with a `tags` table linked to the books table. Could someone point me to the right direction ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ElementCollection has been introduced in JPA v 2.0: the mapping you've done is correct. However make sure the maven hibernate plugin you use is at the correct version. Hibernate itself is compliant with JPA 2.0 starting at version 3.5.

Comment: W00t ! Thank you. Indeed the plugin used an old version of Hibernate. Updating the pom to a newer version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Tag table : tag_id pk, book_id fk references id from book and any other columns you want
and map you list with something like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="book",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

create your tag class with all your columns from database+ a Book object named book for exemple and map this book with:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
```

Comment: at least this is how i would handle it, but i'm also new to hibernate

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Yes I know that your solution would fit. However, I specifically mentioned that I don't want to create an additional entity.

I think this is the purpose of the `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable` annotations.